# second fgets() after fputs() doesn't wait for input

Tags: c++, std

Why the fgets() after fputs() doesn't wait for input in the following c++ code?

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    const char * fileName = "test.txt";
    const int maxStringSize = 1000;
    FILE * file = fopen(fileName, "W");
    char s[maxStringSize];
    fgets(s, maxStringSize, stdin);
    fputs(s,file);
    fgets(s, maxStringSize, stdin);
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think we would need to know what the input looks like to answer that... Also, I'm not sure what the "W" flag to `fopen()` is supposed to be...

Comment: Great comment! I replaced the Capital W with w and the problem was solved. Thanks for your careful consideration.

Answer (score 0):

What you list looks okay to me, but a couple things to check...

The second fgets call will return immediately if:

1. the end of input is reached (e.g., stdin is coming from a file that has only one line).
2. the first line of input (counting the linefeed) is longer than 999 characters.